# It seems that there is a flaw with Backbone.js TodoMVC application

Tags: backbone.js, todomvc

This refers to http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/.

In app.AppView the render() method gets called many times when adding a single todo.

If I'm not mistaking, having the render() method being called many times is bad. Is this a flaw in the TodoMVC implementation?

Comment: Adding to a collection triggers the `add` event once...?

Comment: Yes, @jgillich, the "add" event type calls the callback function once when you add an item to a collection. What does this have to do with the problem, though?

Comment: Calling `render` multiple times is absolutely fine unless you rely on it only being called once. It all depends on the implementation but in my Backbone apps I always rendered the entire view when something changed with no issues (and I think that's common practice).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you'd be right.

In the Todo case, however, it seems only the "add" event gets triggered. This is because there apparently isn't (e.g.) a "sync" event since it uses local storage and doesn't actually sync with the server.

In other words, it looks that isn't the case in Todo's very specific case (due to implementation), but in most cases registering a handler on "all" events would trigger the rendering multiple times.

Comment: David, why do you think that the render() method being called multiple times is not a problem? You are incorrect, the 'all' event listener triggers it's listener many times.

Comment: Oops, I guess I misread the code... The code probably uses the "all" event for simplicity reasons. Otherwise, use the "add" and "remove" events (or even just "sync") to react only to the events you care about.